# How to add datetime picker in angular4 CLI project

Tags: angular, datetime, datetimepicker

I need help with date time picker. I have tried https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker in angular4 but not able to show properly. In other words it is not working at all.

I tried to add following in .angularcli.json file, still not able to make it work.

```
     "styles": [
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
            "styles.css",
            "../node_modules/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/css/datetimepicker.css"
          ],
          "scripts": [
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
            "../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js",
            "../node_modules/moment/moment.js",
            "../node_modules/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/datetimepicker.js",
            "../node_modules/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/datetimepicker.templates.js"
          ]
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with Angular yet. See [**this issue**](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/340). Also, if you want a datetimepicker I'd suggest the `@ng-bootstrap/datepicker`.

Comment: Have you tried ng-bootstrap's timepicker? https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am a big fan of PrimeNG. They have good documentation and the components are easy to use.

Check out their [Date Time Picker](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar)

Answer (score 1):

I have created a datetime popup component found here, which is both the ngx-bootstrap datepicker and timepicker combined

https://github.com/Gillardo/ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup

Answer (score 1):

That component only works with Angular 5+. Instructions for using it are in the readme. See https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/